# Add a new row with data to an existing repeater in ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

i am trying to add a new row with data to an existing repeater in acf.There is no error but this code unable to insert data in database.
this is what i have tried

```
$row = array(
    'vacation_from_date'    => '20/10/2017',
    'vacation_to_date'  => '25/10/2017',
);
$field = get_field_object('vacations','user_' . $user_id);
add_row($field['key'], $row);
```

here is my screenshot for wp-admin[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should it not be

```
add_row('vacations', $row, $post_id);
```

Or is there a reason you are using

```
get_field_object()
```

Comment: i am following this as my reference https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/adding-a-row-to-a-repeater/

this is working but the date is inserted wrong both from date and end date are inserting today's date means 15/11/2017

Comment: What do you get if you do a print_r() on $field?

Comment: $field['key'] is returning field_595dd555958a6

your above code is working fine data is inserted in database finally but dont know why inserting wrong date ,do you have any idea about this....how ACF storing date in database

Comment: Not sure without a bit more info, have you double checked that the keys in your code vacation_from_date & vacation_to_date are correct?

Comment: check the screenshot above i share this image for you

Comment: i got the solution here is the working code
$row = array(
 'vacation_from_date' => date('Ymd',strtotime('20-10-2017')),
 'vacation_to_date' => date('Ymd',strtotime('25-10-2017')),
);
add_row('vacations', $row, 'user_' . $user_id);

this because of bad date format so bydefault ACF storing current date ,any way i really thankful to you for your contribution and time towards me.as because of less reputation i can't give your answer a upvote

Comment: Glad you got sorted.